# How to await inside a dunder method?

Tags: python, async-await, magic-methods

I want to make an async database query and insert it inside `cls.__setitem__` but of course, I can't use `await` inside a sync function. how can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. it's not possible to create an async dunder method so what we could do is using a method that is async but not dunder.

```
class Foo:
    async def setitem(key, item):
        await for_some_stuff()
```

is the solution to my case